# expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token cpp

Tags: c++, struct

I am only starting with cpp and trying to use custom structure.
which looks like this :

```c
typedef struct ws2811_t
{
    uint64_t render_wait_time;                   //< time in µs before the next render can run
    struct ws2811_device *device;                //< Private data for driver use
    const rpi_hw_t *rpi_hw;                      //< RPI Hardware Information
    uint32_t freq;                               //< Required output frequency
    int dmanum;                                  //< DMA number _not_ already in use
    ws2811_channel_t channel[RPI_PWM_CHANNELS];
} ws2811_t;
```

and that's how I am trying to define it:

```cpp
ws2811_channel_t ledstring = {
        .gpionum = LED_PIN,
        .invert = LED_INVERT,
        .count = LED_COUNT,
        .brightness = LED_BRIGHTNESS,
    };
    ws2811_t initString = {
        .freq = LED_FREQ_HZ,
        .dmanum = LED_DMA,
        .channel[LED_CHANNEL] = ledstring,
    };
```

But I am getting error: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token .channel[LED_CHANNEL] = ledstring,`

Why is that? And why other variables works fine and only that one gives error?

Comment: This looks like C to me. How are you compiling the code?

Comment: This uses a feature known as [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers). It's new in C++20; apparently, the compiler you use doesn't support it. It appeared in the C language earlier; I guess that's where you learned it.

Comment: well, it did work at the end, I removed `.channel[LED_CHANNEL] = ` before `ledstring`
but I would like to know why. I found that syntax in the link you provided.
library and struct is from C, but I am actually using it in Cpp. 
Is there other way to define it with naming  params I am defining ?

Comment: You're using [a C library](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x), and it does not appear to have any compatibility wrappers for C++. I strongly recommend you do not try to use this instead in C++ without knowing what you're doing (no offence). Do it in C, or find a C++ developer to help you integrate it into your project.

Comment: That's the problem, I have Cpp project that I have to integrate that C library in it. No other way. So far it appears to work to the point I need it. But you are right. Wrapper would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here bulk  and basic transcription C -> C++ of your code.
struct is class with all public by default.

```
struct ws2811_t{
    uint64_t render_wait_time;                   //< time in µs before the next render can run
    struct ws2811_device *device;                //< Private data for driver use
    const rpi_hw_t *rpi_hw;                      //< RPI Hardware Information
    uint32_t freq;                               //< Required output frequency
    int dmanum;                                  //< DMA number _not_ already in use
    ws2811_channel_t channel[RPI_PWM_CHANNELS];
};

ws2811_channel_t ledstring;

ledstring.gpionum = LED_PIN;
ledstring.invert = LED_INVERT;
ledstring.count = LED_COUNT;
ledstring.brightness = LED_BRIGHTNESS;

ws2811_t initString;

initString.freq = LED_FREQ_HZ;
initString.dmanum = LED_DMA;
initString.channel[LED_CHANNEL] = ledstring;
```